# Getting assembly version of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, version

I have a program that i just built an installer for with wix and im now trying to get the assemblyversion of my program where the tutorial i look at us the GetAssemblyIdentity but where i do not see how im supposed to do this for my app quz its not a console app! the tutorial im looking at is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM and at time stamp 1h 28 min he starts looking at assembly versions and how to get them for your installer but i do not really understand how to do this with a wpf app. what i have tried this far is

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\WPFAPP\bin\$(C)">


</GetAssemblyIdentity>

</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
```

WPFAPP is a placeholder for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

You can use $(MSBuildProjectName) 
So, specify

```
<TargetName>$(ProjectName)</TargetName>
```

In your *.csproj

And then you can use  $(MSBuildProjectName)  as Assembly name. 
To get access to this variable you should write in wixproj

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>ProjectName=%(MSBuildProjectName)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

List of availables variables you can see here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019

**SECOND SOLUTION:**

So, if you want to use versions. See example here.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\MyApp\bin\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

You should specify Assembly file (dll and exe files is both files of .Net and .exe file can be specified here too).

Then you can use BuildVersionVariable like here:

```
<Product Id="*" 
         Name="WixProject1" 
         Language="1033" 
         Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" 
         Manufacturer="WixProject1" 
         UpgradeCode="c93e09b9-9e8f-444c-a35b-84beb2c3788f">
...
</Product>
```

p.s. You can combine this approaches and get some info from one path and some info from another. The main IDEA to define constants in project file and then get acces s to it from WIX

Comment: in what file in the .wixproj

Comment: I change the answer

Comment: Does it matter where in my csproj?

Comment: It should be in *.wixproj

Comment: If you already have <Target Name="BeforeBuild"> then add it to there.

Comment: well it does not find Projectversion in the product file

Comment: Excuse me, it should be "$(var.BuildVersion)"

Comment: it tells me cant find file

Comment: Please replace ..\MyApp\bin\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe to path to your own file